# How to separate JSDoc by file/module

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3

When I generate docs, it places all of the function documentation within one file.

Other than invoking JSDoc multiple times for each file and then renaming, is there a way to separate the docs using a tag or flag?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably generate the documentation per file basis. This is configurable via [Command-line arguments to JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-commandline.html) or by [Configuring JSDoc with conf.json](http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html). You are able to specify directory, where your JS files are located and/or separate files to be included and excluded.

Answer (score 0):

The links in the previous answer were broken, so what I found worked was using the @module tag at the top of each file, and then using a jsdoc.json with opts/recurse: true.